# Is there a equivalent norm on $L^p$ induced by inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, inner-products

> Suppose $L^p[a,b]$ is the normed space with the usual norm $\|f\|_p=(\int_a^b|f(x)|^p\mathrm{d}x)^{1/p}$. By the parallelogram equality, we know the norm is induced by an inner product iff $p=2$. However, for $p\neq 2$, I wonder can we define an inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$ on $L^p$, inducing a new norm $\|\cdot\|=\sqrt{(\cdot,\cdot)}$ such that the new norm is equivalent to the usual $L^p$ norm.

I tend to believe this is not true. Appreciate a valid proof!

Comment: With such a norm $L^p$ would be a Hilbert space, thus isomorphic to its dual $L^q$ ($1/p+1/q=1$). But $L^p$ and $L^q$ are not isomorphic if $p \not=q$, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79713/can-lp-mathbbr-and-lq-mathbbr-be-isomorphic

Comment: Could you explain more detailed why in this case its dual is $L^q$?

Comment: The dual is not $L^q$ anymore in the sense of "the dual is isometric to $L^q$" but the dual is still isomorphic to $L^q$. With a new equivalent norm on $L^p$ you get a new equivalent norm on $(L^p)^\ast$ and the former isometry between $(L^p)^\ast$ and $L^q$ is still an isomorphism.

Comment: So you mean $(L^p,\|\cdot\|_{L^p})^*\cong(L^q,\|\cdot\|_{L^q})$ and $(L^p,\|\cdot\|)^*\cong(L^p,\|\cdot\|)$? How to conclude contradiction?

Comment: I mean $(L^p,\|\cdot\|_{L^p}) \simeq (L^p,\|\cdot\|) \simeq  (L^p,\|\cdot\|)^\ast \simeq (L^q,\|\cdot\|_{L^q})$. The continuous linear functionals $\varphi:L^p \to \mathbb{R}$ are the same with respect to both norms $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$ and $\|\cdot\|$ and the functional norms are equivalent.